# eclipse on linux

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I was running eclipse on Ubuntu Linux. What I have noticed is some icons were missing for File->New->(the items appear in submenu) package,folder,etc. Is this the problem with Ubuntu linux or all the eclipse which is installed on linux?

Thanks
Bhanu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many later versions of Gnome have menu icons disabled by default (my refresh icon is gone as well).  If this is your problem you can get them back by using:

1. Select System > Preferences > Appearance from the menu.
2. This displays a tabbed panel, labeled 'Appearance Preferences'.
3. Select the Interface tab, and check the "Show icons in menus".
4. Select Close.
5. The menu icons should be back.

See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1246454

Sigh. also https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=539993

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem earlier I have ran the below steps and it got fixed. Try to re-install eclipse by giving the below commands

`sudo apt-get remove eclipse` then 
`sudo apt-get install eclipse`

Let me know if it resolves. Good Luck :-)

Comment: which version and type of eclipse it will install? I need eclipse 3.6 plugin development version. Any way i will give your steps.Thanks a lot...

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall eclipse`

Comment: Do u think the problem is similar to this link? http://support.replaysolutions.com/entries/207270-missing-icons-and-buttons-when-using-eclipse-plug-in-with-ubuntu-9-10-or-10-04

Comment: not exactly.. I am missing some icons for File->New->package folder,etc..rest of the things fine for me. Infact i have not noticed anything else.

Comment: Is it because of missing configuration for GTK?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>}"
```

Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185714